Would a ball on a long straight plank roll as if it was curved?
If I have an extremely long plank sitting on the surface of the planet (a). If it is sufficiently long, would a ball on the end roll towards the middle as if it were curved (b)?
I'm assuming this would be the case as there would be a horizontal component of acceleration from gravity in relation to the ball's fixed path.


Short answer: Yes.

If the plank is held fixed (i.e., it cannot bend nor tilt nor anything of the sort), then the gravitational field sourced by the planet will attract the ball towards the middle, similar to what you would expect of a curved plank. The reason, as you said, is because there would be a horizontal component of the gravitational force.
